# How to extract datetime from chunk of HTML

Tags: html, google-chrome, beautifulsoup

I have a piece of HTML that includes a datetime like this

```
<time datetime="2023-01-06 05:00:00" data-format="article-display" data-show-date="always" data-show-time="today-only" data-timestamp="1672981200" itemprop="datePublished" class="author-details__timestamp formatTimeStampEs6" full-date="05.01.2023">6th January</time>
```

I've used the copy JS from Chrome inspector and had this returned

```
#article > div.mar-article > div > div.mar-article__timestamp > time

def extract_time(data):
    """Extract the time from the HTML of the article page."""
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
    # Use the select_one() method to find the time element
    time_element = soup.find("time", class_="datetime")
    print(time_element)
    return time_element
```

Why does it return None?

I'm confused as I don't know how to return just the datetime.

Comment: What does `print(soup.find("time"))` show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element do not have a *class* called `datetime` but you could select it by its *attribute* `datetime` (*provided that the corresponding element is also present in the soup*):

```
soup.select_one('time[datetime]').get('datetime')
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup('<time datetime="2023-01-06 05:00:00" data-format="article-display" data-show-date="always" data-show-time="today-only" data-timestamp="1672981200" itemprop="datePublished" class="author-details__timestamp formatTimeStampEs6" full-date="05.01.2023">6th January</time>')

soup.select_one('time[datetime]').get('datetime')
```

##### Output

```
2023-01-06 05:00:00
```